# jQuery Event not firing in particular scenario

Tags: jquery

here is my scenario:

Having a simple text-input and two events: Focus In / Out.

In Focus In a "clear" button will appear over the text-input (aligned to the right).
In Focus Out the "clear" button will be hidden.

This two actions simply uses a .show() / .hide() jQuery methods.

The "clear" button has a click event, which is nothing but setting the text-input value as empty.

Problem is: When trying to click over the "clear" button, the Focus Out event gets fired before the "clear" button event, so "clear" button is hidden and click event is not triggered.

I already tried attaching the event (to the clear button) with .on / .live / etc.

The Only workaround i have found (so far) is to hide the clear button (which it happends in the Focus Out event) with a timeOut, but i'm not sure how reliable this solution can be.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: please post code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var clear_button_timeout_id = null;
var clear_button = '<button class="clear">Clear</button>';

$('div').on('click', '.clear', function () {
    $(this).parent().find('input').val('');
});

$('input')
    .on('focus', function () {
        if (!$(this).parent().find('.clear').length) {
            $(this).after(clear_button);       
        }

        if (clear_button_timeout_id) {
            clearTimeout(clear_button_timeout_id);
        }
    })
    .on('blur', function () {
        var that = this;

        clear_button_timeout_id = setTimeout(function () {
            $(that).parent().find('.clear').remove();
        }, 2000)
    });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ethagnawl/am2eu/)

Comment: Hi ethagnawl, that is pretty much the workaround i have found for it, only issue is that with this solution, if for example you change the timeout to lets say 50 miliseconds you will see it doesn't work as expected (not enough time for the input event to be fired), that's what i was talking about being a reliable solution.

Any other possible workaround in mind?, Thanks anyway ethagnawl :)

Comment: In that case, why would you set the timeout to be so small? ;) There's no harm in having the button around for a few extra seconds. The focus handler could destroy any existing buttons to ensure there are never two visible at the same time, if that's your concern. The other idea I had was to use mouseover/out on a parent element, but that doesn't really work in the case of keyboard navigation...

Comment: Hi, i know that maybe some other workarounds might work fine, but for what i need i will keep this solution as the right one. Also keeping in mind that the timeout delay can affect the behavior. cya!

Answer (score 0):

I would have to play with it to be certain, but can't you just set the button's width (and padding/border/margin) to 0 instead of hiding it? That way it's still on the page, and I think the click event will get through to it.

Edit:
No, wait, I just realized it won't work. The text box loses focus when your mouse button goes down, and the click event won't fire until you release the mouse button.

Comment: Instead of hiding it, set the width to 0, and instead of showing it, set the width to normal. Click on it when it's visible, the onBlur will fire, setting its width to 0 (thereby making it invisible), and then I think the onClick will still work... And I guess you just realized that, because you deleted your comment.

Comment: Hi, so far ill stay with the timeOut workaround, when i get home i will give it a try to your solution, btw, i didn't deleted any comments, i just edited the answer i wrote for another user, cheers!

Comment: Yeah, someone else had a comment asking how you were supposed to click on a 0-width button, then deleted it while I was responding.